# Calculating frequency with hall effect sensor and arduino in LabVIEW

Tags: arduino, labview, sensors

my current VI is using LINX to get voltage measurements from an arduino analog pin and displaying the data (current,power etc). I have a hall effect sensor set up that would get the pulses from a vibrating structure and potentially display the frequency at which the the structure is vibrating on the same VI. How can i implement this with my current design? I have tried to come up with a way to count the number of pulses in LabVIEW but couldn't find a way to efficiently do that so i can do the calculation of the frequency.  Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: What's the period of the vibrations - seconds, milliseconds, microseconds? Is a simple threshold enough to detect the pulses reliably or do you need to extract the signal from a noisy background or drifting baseline, etc?

Comment: The period of the vibrations is controlled and variable.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I've tried what @SlowlyButSurely suggested and it works for counting the pulses, but I don't seem to get accurate frequency results from the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up your timestamp grab similar to this where once an edge is detected, or a bool True from your digital read, a timestamp is then added into the shift register array.  Then do the frequency calculation from time differences between stamps after a number of stamps have been collected so you can average them out (if need be).  The when you're grabbing a timestamp you have to make sure it is a stamp made as close to the same time as when the edge detect is generated.  (Sorry, all I have available is LV 7.1 and I had to install it to make any code, wow is it old.)

Oh, the false case here is just a pass through for the shift register.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an edge detection function block in LV, You can use this and grab a timestamp every time a rising edge is detected and then can determine the frequency from that calculation.

[image]

Comment: @Super95 SO is not letting me help fully because of privileges... my rep isn't high enough and apparently my questions aren't helpful enough.  Sigh.  Regardless I'll try.  

Going back to your original block diagram every time your digital read gives a boolean high grab a timestamp and stick both the boolean high and timestamp into an array that carries through the while loop.  Then calculate your frequency off of an average of the time differences between these timestamps.  An individual measurement can be quite off unless you're using LV realtime

Comment: I'll install the only version of LV I have available and get back to you in a bit with code....